# Creating polymer element

Tags: html, polymer

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <script src="bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>
 <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer-mini.html">
</head>
<body>
<polymer-element name="x-foo" noscript>
 <template>
  Hello x-foo
 </template>
</polymer-element>
<x-foo></x-foo>
</body>
</html>
```

Hello Guys, i'm actually new to polymer and i have been trying to run my first stuff on it but its not forth coming and its a bit frustrating you know .
the above code is not showing me anything on my browser and i don't know what i'm doing wrong because there is nothing i can see as the output on my browser after serving and i'm using google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The code above is for `Polymer 0.x` and not `Polymer 1.x`. If you want to work with 1.x version you should have a look at Polymer's own [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/feature-overview) for same for other topics related to 1.x.